# Can you tap the same land twice in a turn?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So i am wondering if you could use cards to allow you to play a land, tap it, send it back to your hand, then tap it again.

For example:

1. Play forest, tap it
2. Play [Selesnya Sanctuary](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSelesnya%20Sanctuary%5d), send forest to hand
3. Play [Urban Evolution](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUrban%20Evolution%5d)
4. Play forest, tap it

And maybe

5. Untap it with [Kiora's Follower](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKiora%27s%5d%2b%5bFollower%5d) to tap it a total of 3 times

Does this work?

Comment: There are no limits on how many times an object can be tapped in a given turn, and only the Loyalty abilities of Planeswalkers are limited in the number of times they can be activated in a turn. (You can only activate a Planeswalker's loyalty abilities if none have been activated that turn.) Of course, some cards might have abilities that impose additional limits.

Answer (score 7):

I think the other answer by doppelgreener puts too much emphasis on 400.7. I don't think that that rule is relevant at all. Rather, we have

> 107.5. The tap symbol is {T}. The tap symbol in an activation cost means “Tap this permanent.” A permanent that’s already tapped can’t be tapped again to pay the cost. A creature’s activated ability with the tap symbol in its activation cost can’t be activated unless the creature has been under its controller’s control continuously since their most recent turn began.

along with

> 110.6. A permanent’s status is its physical state. There are four status categories, each of which has two 
>   possible values: tapped/untapped, flipped/unflipped, face up/face down, and phased in/phased out. 
>   Each permanent always has one of these values for each of these categories.
>
> 110.6b Permanents enter the battlefield untapped, unflipped, face up, and phased in unless a spell or 
>   ability says otherwise

So nothing in rule 110.6 says that a permanent remembers that it has previously been tapped; it is either tapped or untapped, and that's it. Nothing in rule 107.5 cares what has happened to a permanent earlier when you decide whether the tap symbol is a cost you're allowed to pay (except summoning sickness on creatures). Only its status in that exact moment.

If a permanent is untapped (regardless of why), then you are allowed to activate abilities it has with the tap symbol in the cost (unless it's a creature with summoning sickness). When you play the forest in step 4, it comes into play untapped as per 110.6b. You can then tap it to get a green mana. When it has been untapped by Kiora's follower, it is untapped, which means 107.5 once again allows you to activate its ability.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's fine.

(Strictly speaking one thing isn't fine: you seem to describe playing a forest and then a Selesnya's Sanctuary in the same turn, which requires one more land play than you've got this turn! But let's just assume you played another Urban Evolution between steps 1 and 2 to let you do this.)

First, when you're dealing with zone changes, [this rule becomes really important](https://blogs.magicjudges.org/rules/cr400/):

> **400.7** An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence.

This means when that forest card moves between your hand and your battlefield, it's effectively a *completely* new thing as far as the game cares. When it returns to your hand and is played again later, the new forest has *nothing* to do with the old forest which just happened to be represented by the same card. They enter a new zone in a brand new state each time.

This means when you play the forest initially, you can tap it like a normal forest. When you put it back onto the battlefield again later after Urban Evolution, you have a different brand new forest, and it's untapped, and you can tap it again.

(There are some exceptions listed in the full text of rule 400.7. These exceptions mostly have to do with effects that make cards change zones and which *must* be able to do things with the same cards in the new zone.)

> Untap it with Kiora's Follower to tap it a total of 3 times

Yep, that's one of the primary uses of a card like that: tap a land for mana, then untap it so you can tap it for more mana. If you had *four* [Kiora's Follower](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKiora%27s%5d%2b%5bFollower%5d)s, you could do this another three times. Back in Theros, contemporary with Kiora's Follower, we'd preferably do this with our [Nykthos, Shrine to Nyx](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNykthos%2c%20Shrine%20to%20Nyx%5d) for a considerable amount of mana.

Comment: Thanks! I now have to find a way to fit temple of the false gods into one of my decks to abuse that. This is bound to be fun!

Comment: I suggest that the answer be generalized to cover all lands, which is the what the title of the question and the first sentence of the question body ask about, as opposed to only covering the specific example of "Forest". I also suggest that the answer not mention rule 400.7, as even though the question involves a zone change, it is not the zone change that allows the Forest to be tapped again. Rather, it is the untapped state of the Forest that allows it to be tapped again. I deleted all of my previous comments, as they weren't phrased in a way that could be understood as a suggestion.

Comment: @Rainbolt Thank you for this suggestion. I think that's not a bad idea, so I'll revise. I'd still like to clarify the land card itself doesn't get "spent" somehow, but I can put less emphasis on that.